# Mapping across antimeridian with ggmap and Stamen maps

Tags: r, ggmap, stamen-maps

I'm trying to make a map using {ggmap} and Stamen maps. The map needs to span the [antimeridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180th_meridian) at 180° longitude. Specifically, I want the map to extend from -190° to -60° longitude.

[This](http://maps.stamen.com/terrain/#4/-46.53/-124.06) is roughly the map that I want, so it's definitely possible using Stamen maps.

However, when I try to retrieve the tiles for this using `get_stamenmap()` I get multiple HTTP 503 errors ("Failed to aquire tile") for tiles that lie on the "other" side of the antimeridian.

```
library(ggmap)

map <- get_stamenmap(
  bbox = c(
    left   =   -190.0,
    right  =   -60.0,
    top    =   -35.0,
    bottom =   -70.0),
  zoom = 3
)

ggmap(map)
```

This is what the resulting map looks like (note the missing tiles on the left side of the map).

[image: Map not crossing antimeridian.]

I have similar issues when I add 360° to both the `left` and `right` extremes, only the missing tiles are then on the right side of the map.

It makes sense that the bounding box for these maps is constrained to lie between -180° and 180° of longitude, however, surely there must be a workaround to cater for maps which straddle the antimeridian?

Thanks,
Andrew.

As an aside, it's possible to do this using Google Maps but I don't want to be encumbered with having to provide a Google API key since this is going to be presented as an exercise at a workshop.

```
get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -135, lat = -40), zoom = 2)
```

Comment: Was this ever resolved with get_stamenmap? I am currently having this same issue